# On the meaning of the terms in straight line fitting

Tags: regression, linear-model, regression-coefficients, linear

In straight line fitting, the model is:
$$y_{i} = \alpha + \beta x_{i} + \epsilon_{i}$$

Here, for each $i$, $y_{i}$ and $\epsilon_{i}$ are considered to be random variables, where as $x_{i}$ is understood to be "fixed".

What I don't understand is in regards to which universe, or experiment, these are considered to be random variables.

One theory that I was able to come up with is that for each $i$, things are understood from the perspective of a universe $\Omega_{i}$, one representing the experiment of performing an $(X,Y)$ measure over the individual $i$. In this universe, and because of measurement errors, each experiment could give rise to different values for X and Y (for the same individual $i$) and, in the context of Linear Regression, the assumption of weak exogenity would affirm that each of these experiments would give rise to the same measure of X, and hence the error-free connotation. If this was the case, $x_{i}$ would represent the measured value of $X$ over the individual $i$, but $y_{i}$ would be the actual value of $Y$ for the individual $i$ (because of the added error). Intuitively, this interpretation seems to be in line with the assertion that the mean of each $\epsilon_{i}$ is null.

Another theory is that, instead of representing the experiment of performing an $(X,Y)$ measure for the individual $i$, $\Omega_{i}$ represents the experiment of "picking" a straight line (and thus two numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$) . In this universe, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ would too be random variables, not just $y_{i}$ and $\epsilon_{i}$.

I'm not sure if either of these is correct. My guess is that both of them are wrong. For this, I'm asking for an exact explanation of the terms aformentioned, as most of the literature I encountered fails to explain what they actually mean or refer to.

Comment: Perhaps the difficulty arises because there are *two* general settings in which this model is applied.  In the experimental setting, you *set* the value of $x_i$ and read off the corresponding value of $y_i.$  In the observational setting, you *observe* the ordered pair $(x_i,y_i).$ Your interest lies in understanding how $y$ behaves *conditional* on $x.$  Another difficulty arises because a Bayesian analysis might very well model $\alpha,$ $\beta,$ or both as random variables, too; but classically, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are fixed numbers (parameters).

Comment: Not being clear about which universe (or setting) the variables are defined over is also not helpful to understand what your variables are intended to model.

Comment: That's an extremely abstract statement.  In applications, the meanings of the variables are often perfectly clear.

Comment: *"In the experimental setting, you set the value of xi and read off the corresponding value of $y_{i}$"*  What do you mean by the corresponding value of $y_{i}$? Do you mean the one that is found when measuring the Y variable over an individual whose measure of X is equal to $x_{i}$? If so, there could be multiple $y_{i}$ corresponding to the same $x_{i}$

Comment: That's completely correct.  It is one of the principal reasons we model $y_i$ as a random variable.

Comment: So, in the experimental setting, for each $i$ we associate  a universe that is the set of all the pairs of the possible measures of X and Y where X is found to be equal to $x_{i}$. And $y_{i}$ is the random variable that associates each of these pairs to the their respective second members?

Comment: That's one way to do it.  It's perhaps a little simpler to imagine a population consisting of $(x,y)$ pairs.  In the observational setting you sample randomly from it.  In the experimental setting you first extract all the outcomes having a given value of $x$ and you sample randomly from that subset.  In more generality, though, you construct a population consisting of pairs of $n$-*vectors* $(\mathbf x, \mathbf y)$ and you sample a single outcome from that population.  This is required for modeling non-independent responses.

Comment: Finally, people wishing to be fully general will model the experimental version as a stochastic process in which $x$ is in the parameter space.  This permits rigorous asymptotic analysis, because the stochastic process formulation allows for the sample size to grow arbitrarily large in a consistent way.

Comment: Perhabs I was mistaken when saying that for each $i$, the universe is the set of all pairs of the possible measures of X and Y where x is found to be equal to $x_{i}$. Perhabs it should be **the set of all pairs of the possible measures of X and Y over the individual $i$**. This way the same measures of X over the individual $i$ could give rise to different values, and this is perhabs where the assumption of weak exogeneity becomes relevant, stating that different measures of X over the same individual lend the same result and thus the variable is error-free as a consequence.